# collecting/pulling numbers from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

consider the script below..

```
$('#accessories').editable({ 
    validate: function(value) {
              // solution will be placed here
    }
});
```

if variable 'value' has the string value of "RUST-PROOFING (2),SPOILER (1),ALARM (2),SIDE-SKIRT (1)" , how could i sum (inclosed with parenthesis) the numbers (2) (1) (2) (1) from 'value' variable.

Comment: I guess your best bet is matching a RegExp and get the number based on the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/Tc7wG/)

I left to you to add some exception like if a number is the last thing in the string, because my code don't look for it and will not add it.

All you have to do is loop the string, check if it's a number, if it is, add it to a var and continu to loop, when the next char is not a number, add what you have build up.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNumber(str[i])) {
        strNumber += str[i];
    } else if (strNumber != "") {
        retVal += Number(strNumber);
        strNumber = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: shryme.. thanks too... what is need to sum-up are those numbers enclosed with ().. i'm trying some ideas now.. :)

Comment: You can first detect for "(" and add it to strNumber, then if strNumber contain "(" or a number as the last element, look for adding new numbers, if the character is ")" transform it into a number (without the first element because it will be "(" ) and tadam

Comment: Remember to upvote answers that helped you, if you only needed 1 number inside the ( ) then the answer of Mark was good too!

Comment: hehehe i found a bug.. if number > 9 will sum it wrong :) solution limits 1-9 only... i'm trying to fix it...

Comment: That's why I was adding them to strNumber, your new code look if a number is between (), if you want more then one number inside, you will need to detect the first (, then add all number between until the closing )

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. First you setup a regex to look for numbers in your string, this returns an array of matches, then you can pass this array into a custom function which multiplies all numbers in an array together.

```
var str = "RUST-PROOFING (2),SPOILER (1),ALARM (2),SIDE-SKIRT (1)";
var re = /[\d+]/g //Match only numbers (along the whole string)
var matches = str.match(re);
var total = multiply(matches); //Pass your array of matches to your multiply function;
alert(total); //4

function multiply(arr) { //Multiplies all numbers in an array and returns the total value;
    var num = 0;
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        num += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKYpv/)

Comment: it's not working, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/uKYpv/2/ It read 21 like 2 and 1 and not like a whole, and he wanted to add the numbers, not multiply them.

Comment: My bad, thought he meant multiply them, i've amended code and fiddle to reflect this

Comment: But the code still lack in the fact that, if the string is "22 23" it will make 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 instead of 22 + 23

Comment: thank u mark, u gave me an idea... it does sum it correct, however, if a string has a number like SPOILER1 (1), this sum-up to 2.. numbers to sum are those enclosed with () only.. but thanks so much, i'm in a process of modifying your code

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys (especially to Shryme and Mark).. here's a wrap-up... hoping this will help a newb like me in the future..

```
$('#accessories').editable({ 
validate: function(value) {
    $ntot = add(value.toString());
    $('#npoints').editable('setValue', $ntot);
}
});

function add(str) {
var retVal = 0;
var strNumber = "";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNumber(str[i]) && (str[i-1]=="(" || str[i+1]==")")) {
        strNumber += str[i];
    } else if (strNumber != "") {
        retVal += Number(strNumber);
        strNumber = "";
    }
}
return retVal;
}

function isNumber(n) {
    if (n == "") return false;
    return !isNaN(n);
}
```